# Unable to select element using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: Sample code]

I am unable to find the element either by XPath, CssSelector, ClassName, etc...for the highlighted text (which is a button).  Have the following code:

```
driverChrome.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
driverChrome.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
IWebElement optionsGear = driverChrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("html body div#app.d2l-typography div#root-wrapper div.main-wrapper div.root div.main div.navigation-container div.nav-header div.options-header div.overall-options-container div.options-dropdown button.button.overall-options"));
optionsGear.Click();
```

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Could it be that this is not the only iframe in page? Try to switch it by id instead of index.

Comment: I tried IWebElement leftPane = driverChrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//html//body//iframe"));
            driverChrome.SwitchTo().Frame(leftPane);  but get the same result.  I can however, execute the code in the Browser Console correctly: document.getElementsByClassName("overall-options")[0].click()

Comment: So... Does it work if you try `driverChrome.SwitchTo().Frame("iFrameResizer0");`?

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Found that putting in an implicit wait resolved the problem: driverChrome.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);